# Google Maps API V3 not showing

Tags: google-maps

Hi I am trying to build a store locator app. For some reason the google maps doesnot show on the onclick event. I have checked the javascript console in Chrome and I have no errors. Could some share some light.I have attached my code below. Could also please explain the cause of such kind of error.
I have copied partial code which I think might be a cause of the problem as my geocode works fine and gives me the names of the places sorted as the nearest to the destination entered in the text field.

```
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latValues[0]; ?>,<?php echo $lngValues[0]; ?>);
    var opts = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        }
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("maps"), opts);
    var infowin = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: ""
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,

        title: ""
    });
```

infowin.open(map, marker);

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
        infowin.open(map, marker);
    });
    var nowRow = document.getElementById('teamRow1');
    function changeMap(n,ob) {
        nowRow.className = "";
        ob.className = "selected";
        nowRow = ob;

        switch(n-1) {
            case 0:
                latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latValues[0]; ?>,<?php echo $lngValues[0]; ?>);
                break;
            case 1:
                latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latValues[1]; ?>,<?php echo $lngValues[1]; ?>);
            break;
            case 2:
                latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latValues[2]; ?>,<?php echo $lngValues[2]; ?>);
            break;
            case 3:
                latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latValues[3]; ?>,<?php echo $lngValues[3]; ?>);
                break;
            case 4:
                latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latValues[4]; ?>,<?php echo $lngValues[4]; ?>);
                break;
            }

            opts = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                navigationControl: true,
                navigationControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
                }
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("maps"), opts);
            infowin = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: ""
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                title: ""
            });
            infowin.open(map, marker);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
                infowin.open(map, marker);
            });
    }
```

Comment: there seem to be some formatting issues with your code...

Comment: I have found the error it was the CSS style and i had missed it. <link rel="stylesheet" href=style.css" type="text/css" /> Thankyou for flagging it.